# To auto adjust content width in ios simulator on rotation by bootstrap

Tags: cordova, twitter-bootstrap, ios-simulator

I am building a phone gap application in phonegap(for iPad Simulator) using bootstrap.

I want to adjust the width of the body while rotating from portrait to landscape using a bootstrap responsive feature.
Is it possible by the way?It can be done by hard coding in the event of rotation by normally adding class to the content selector using jquery.

I want to know whether bootstrap has any in-built feature for this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/729